# Firebase phone auth check if reCAPTCHA flow was triggered

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification)

> The reCAPTCHA flow will only be triggered when SafetyNet is
> unavailable or your device does not pass suspicion checks.
> Nonetheless, you should ensure that both scenarios are working
> correctly.

I want to check if the user was shown the reCAPTCHA screen so I could track it in the app analytics.

I couldn't find any way of achieving this in the docs. Is there something I missed, or is this not available for now?

Comment: Can you add which type of reCaptcha you have selected? Is it a check box?

Comment: I don't choose what type of Recaptcha is shown to the user, firebase decides this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Keep a flag that will be toggled on navigating away from the current `Activity` or `Fragment`. Maybe you need to take care of the case when the user minimized the app (pressing the home, or call), otherwise you'll get inaccurate analytics.

```kotlin
 val authCompleted = AtomicBoolean(false)
```

2. Toggle it when you explicitly need to navigate to next screen,

```kotlin
     override fun onAuthCompleted(){
         if(authCompleted.compareAndSet(false, true)){
             findNavController().navigate(nextDirection)
         }
     }
```

3. If you navigate away without this flag being flipped, means you are either navigating to show reCAPTCHA `ActivityDialog`

```kotlin
    override fun onStop(){
       super.onStop()
       if(!isFinishing && !authCompleted.get()){
         //you are probably given the reCAPTCHA dialog
       }
    }
```